# How do I get Decimal to reflect value correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

I need to perform many math operations on numbers that look like `104.950178` - i.e. having multiple decimal places. It ranges from 4 decimal places to 8 decimal places with an occasional 10 decimal place number.

After much reading on Stack Overflow, I understand that I should not use `float` but instead use `Decimal`, because `float` is base 2 and `Decimal` is base 10. Having many math operations, `float` will give a result with error, which was not what I wanted, so I went with `Decimal`.

Everything was working fine until I encountered:

```
from decimal import *
Decimal(0.1601).quantize(Decimal('.0001'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR) #returned Decimal('0.1600')
```

I need the numbers to be reflected exactly as they are. Can you please advise if there is another number system to use in Python 3, or if there is a way to get Decimal to take the number given as it is without changing its value?

Note: I added the "quantize..." portion of the code due to the comment by Mark to make it a MVCE. I took for granted the output and forgot that every `Decimal` in this part of my code was processed to truncate at 4 decimal points.

Nevertheless, @jonrsharpe is really sharp. He saw my question and immediately knew (before the "quantize..." edit) where the problem was. Thanks!

Comment: `Decimal(0.1601)` has **already lost precision**, because you created the float from the literal then gave *that* to the decimal library. Don't do that. Read the library docs for how to use it correctly.

Comment: `Decimal(0.1601) #returned Decimal(1.600)` <- Typo? If `Decimal(0.1601)` is giving you back `Decimal('1.600')`, that's a serious bug. I doubt it's giving you `Decimal('0.1600')`, either. Can you show the actual code and output?

Comment: Hi @MarkDickinson, it is not a typo. Please try the code out yourself to discover. It is not a bug either. jonrsharpe's comment gave a clue.

Comment: @clw - it most probably is a typo in your questions code-comment.  look for the digit points. Decimal(`0.1601`) might give you Decimal(`'0.1600'`)  - but not Decimal(`1.600`) wich would be 10 times as much as the float.

Comment: @clw I did. On my machine, I get the expected result: typing `Decimal(0.1601)` at the Python prompt and hitting return gets me: `Decimal('0.1600999999999999923172566695939167402684688568115234375')`. I'm finding it hard to imagine how you got `Decimal(1.600)`, `Decimal('1.600')`, or even `Decimal('0.1600')`. Again, please show the *exact code* that you're using to define the `Decimal` instance and to print it. Are you using string formatting? Are you changing rounding modes or precision at any point?

Comment: Voting to close because of the lack of an MVCE, but this is also a much-asked question and could be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the MVCE; I've removed my close vote. Note that you're _still_ claiming that an input of 0.16 gives an output of 1.6, though.

Comment: Can't believe after reading the same post and comments over and over I did not spot that. Thank you for your patience @MarkDickinson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
a = 0.1601
Decimal(a)
```

I used:

```
a = '0.1601'
Decimal(a)
```

Defined it as a `string` instead, and `Decimal` reflected the value exactly. I hope this helps someone.